# Get image from image view and then crop (Android Image Cropper Library)

Tags: android, cropper

Hi I have been using Android Image Cropper library, though I have been able to crop images from getting them from the gallery.

But how would I start the image crop activity if I would just get the image from a Imageview and not selecting from the gallery or camera?

I have researched but you can only start the crop activity when using a image URI but maybe someone else has been able to do it.

This is my acitivty:

```
  private Uri mCropImageUri;

 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    txtExtracted = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtRetrieved);

    btnStartCrop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnStartCrop);

    imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgView);

    View v1 = getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView();
    v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(v1.getDrawingCache());
    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

   btnStartCrop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
    });
  }

@Override
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (requestCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {
        CropImage.ActivityResult result = CropImage.getActivityResult(data);
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            ((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.quick_start_cropped_image)).setImageURI(result.getUri());
            Toast.makeText(this, "Cropping successful, Sample: " + result.getSampleSize(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else if (resultCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_RESULT_ERROR_CODE) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Cropping failed: " + result.getError(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}

private void startCropImageActivity(Uri imageUri) {
    CropImage.activity(imageUri)
            .setGuidelines(CropImageView.Guidelines.ON)
            .setMultiTouchEnabled(true)
            .start(this);
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help regarding this, and if anyone has opinions or better ways to go it will be greatly appreciated :D

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with [picaso](http://Picasso.with(context).load(%22http://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png%22).into(imageView);).

```
@Override
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (requestCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {
        CropImage.ActivityResult result = CropImage.getActivityResult(data);
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            Picasso.with(this)
                .load(result.getUri())
                .into(((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.quick_start_cropped_image)));

        } else if (resultCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_RESULT_ERROR_CODE) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Cropping failed: " + result.getError(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```